# Updating time in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, time, sdk, updating, self-updating

I'm using the code provided below to display time and date. can anyone help me with atuomatically changing the time by seconds and the date by the day?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

NSLog(@"\n"

      "theDate: |%@| \n"
      "theTime: |%@| \n"
      , theDate, theTime);

[dateFormat release];
[timeFormat release];
[now release];
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what  you mean by update? Do you want the value logged to the console to automatically change?

Comment: Yea I want to automatically change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSTimer, specifically [scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:).  You can use 1 as a time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NSDateComponents` class. For example, to add one day and one second to a date:

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
unsigned unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSCalendar *curr = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
oneDay.day = 1;
oneDay.second = 1;

NSDate* adjustedDate = [curr dateByAddingComponents:oneDay 
                                             toDate:startDate 
                                            options:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Date and Time programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.pdf)